# Grouping Rows By Insertion Order

Tags: mysql

I have a table as follows;

| RECORDREF | SHIFTREF | DATECREATED |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 2023/09/19 |
| 2 | 3 | 2023/09/19 |
| 3 | 3 | 2023/09/19 |
| 4 | 3 | 2023/09/20 |
| 5 | 4 | 2023/09/20 |
| 6 | 4 | 2023/09/20 |
| 7 | 4 | 2023/09/20 |
| 8 | 4 | 2023/09/20 |
| 9 | 5 | 2023/09/20 |
| 10 | 5 | 2023/09/20 |
| 11 | 5 | 2023/09/20 |
| 12 | 3 | 2023/09/20 |
| 13 | 3 | 2023/09/20 |
| 14 | 3 | 2023/09/21 |
| 15 | 3 | 2023/09/21 |

From the table above, I want to group the data according to the SHIFTREF column. But I don't want to combine the data in first four rows and last four rows. Although the SHIFTREF values are same, I want the first four row and the last four row to be considered as different groups, because there are rows with different SHIFTREF values between these groups. So the resulting group summary should be as follows;

| SHIFTREF | COUNT | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 4 | 2023/09/19 |
| 4 | 4 | 2023/09/20 |
| 5 | 3 | 2023/09/20 |
| 3 | 4 | 2023/09/20 |

Please also note that the DATECREATED column cannot be used in GROUP BY statement because rows with the same SHIFTREF value may have different DATECREATED values!
What type of a GROUP BY statement can achieve such a summary operation?

[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTk7R.png)

[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aB8C.png)

Comment: explain your logic, why no group for 09/21 and shiftref 3 ?

Comment:  [why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: What is your MySQL server version **precisely**?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure your logic is flawed, no offence ;-)

There are 3 records with Shiftref "3" and date 19/9. So why would count(*) ever be 4?

There are also 3 records with shiftref "3" and date 20/9. So again, why would count(*) be 4 here? Doesn't make sense.

Then there is also no mention of shiftref "3" with date 21/9.

Technically your question is possible, but then it's lacking detail of logic, IE which records should be grouped.

```
SELECT
  shiftref,
  COUNT(*) AS HowMany,
  datecreated
FROM test123
GROUP BY shiftref, datecreated
```

Comment: Because shift 3 starts at 20:30 and ends at 08:30 next day, GROUP BY statement will be wrong when datecreated is used.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH
cte1 AS (
  SELECT *, LAG(shiftref) OVER (ORDER BY recordref) lagshiftref
  FROM test
),
cte2 AS (
  SELECT *, SUM(CASE WHEN shiftref = lagshiftref THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY recordref) groupno
  FROM cte1
)
SELECT MIN(shiftref) shiftref,
       COUNT(*) `count`,
       MIN(datecreated) `date`
FROM cte2 
GROUP BY groupno
ORDER BY MIN(recordref);
```

| shiftref | count | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 4 | 2023-09-19 |
| 4 | 4 | 2023-09-20 |
| 5 | 3 | 2023-09-20 |
| 3 | 4 | 2023-09-20 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XYkvDeGf)

PS. MySQL 8+ needed.

Comment: This solution is exactly what I have been looking for. Thank you very much!